# Azure Pipeline unable to load service index for private package

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have inherited a long standing pipeline that is for our PR builds, building a .net core web service

This has started to fail with the following error:

https://XXXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/XXXX/nuget/v3/index.json. [C:\agent_work\223\s\Core.XXXX.REST.WS.sln]
##[error]Core.XXXX.Repositories\Core.XXXX.Repositories.csproj(0,0): Error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://XXXX.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/XXXX/nuget/v3/index.json.

Things to note:

We have other pipelines using the same service and same oauth token (the option is checked on the pipeline) and they all can seemingly access the file needed.

I can't see this being an issue with the checkin, as it was just some cs files being checked in.

The artifact looks fine and the user being used has access to the feed.

The nuget.config file is present and contains the required config for the feed

Any ideas or pointers on what could be causing the issue would be great. It absolutely feels like some sort of access/permissions type thing, but I haven't a clue where to look/check

Answer (score 0):

Just for an update. I changed the setting of using the selected feed to using the feeds declared in the Nuget.config and this seems to have resolved the issue.

I'm not really sure why this has fixed the issue so won't mark this as an answer yet, I want to investigate further.